# Connecting an old landline phone to FreePBX/VoIP?

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I'm looking to hookup a landline phone with an RJ11 connector to my FreePBX server so I can make and receive calls using that phone. If this is possible, what type of adapter would I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device you are looking for is called an ATA  (Analogue Telephone Adaptor) - I'm sure there are many vendors that make better ones, but Cisco (Linksys) make cheap ones that work well enough until they suddenly die - the SPA1222 and PAP2T , or alternatively you can use an FXS (Foreign Exchange Subscriber) interface under Asterisk or the like.